# Using Rand() populate Multidimensional Array

Tags: c

I am completing an exercise in which I want to create an array and populate it with random and meaningless IP addresses.

It is supposed to be a 2 dimensional `array[5][4]`. It is  5 addresses, each consisting of 4 parts( i.e. {192, 168, 0 ,1}. My trouble comes from using the rand() function to populate only one dimension of the array. I cannot figure out how to do it in a way that:

1. the compiler accepts,
2. won't crash the program, and
3. won't produce an entirely random result.

Although my main issue comes from the for loop `for (int o = 0; o < octets; o++)` below , feel free to comment on any of my code, best practices, etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    const int addresses = 5, octets = 4;
    int ips[addresses][octets];

    for (int a = 0; a < addresses; a++) {
        for (int o = 0; o < octets; o++) {
            ips[octets] = rand() % 255;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < addresses; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < octets; j++) {
            printf("%d ", ips[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler error for this code is... :

```
ipAddressArray.c: In function 'main':
ipAddressArray.c:18:18: error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'int[(s
izetype)octets]' from type 'int'  ps[octets] = rand()%255;
```

Comment: You need to think about what `ips[octets]` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite this loop like

```
for (int a = 0; a < addresses; a++) {
    for (int o = 0; o < octets; o++) {
        ips[a][o] = rand() % 255;
    }
}
```